# How can I set my Java applet's working directory in IDEA?

Tags: java, applet, intellij-idea, japplet

I have been using IntelliJ for a while now and I'm enjoying its suite of features but I'm having a hard time getting the run configurations to work for a java applet.  I have a pre-existing Java tool that uses Swing and I'm using the JApplet class to load those GUI objects as an applet.  The problem is I have a couple configuration files that I need loaded.  I load these from the working directory and from my knowledge, this working directory would normally be the directory in which the applet resides.  I think the major problem is IDEA sets the startup variable:

```
-Didea.launcher.bin.path=IDEA_BIN_DIR
```

I would like to be able to change this but I am seemingly unable to.  I have tried overriding this flag by editing the applets run configuration VM parameters, but IDEA will continue putting the above one in even if I specify something different.

So in short, I'm having a hard time loading a local configuration file because I can't set the working directory for the run configuration in IDEA.  Does anyone know how to get around this or know of a better way of running Java applets that use configuration files, in IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An applet normally runs in a sandbox in a browser, and such an applet can't access the local computer's file system, for security reasons.

Thus it is generally a bad idea to load configuration files from the file system, and "working directory" is not a useful term for an applet.

- If these files change seldom (i.e. in principle only by the developer), you can put them to the applet's class files (i.e. in the jar file, or during development in the directory where the classes will be generated), and use `class.getResource()` or `.getResourceAsStream()` to load them.
- If the configuration files should be definable by the webmaster, put them on the webserver - either at some fixed location relative to `getCodeBase()` or `.getDocumentBase()`, or specify them as parameters to your applet tag in the HTML tag.
- If these are user specific configuration files (which the applet should be able to write), you either need to store them on the server and retrieve/store after a login (i.e. you need some logic at the server side), or you would store them at the client side.

  The current way to do this would be using the JNLP API (in javax.jnlp.*) - there are some interfaces allowing Persistence, or loading/storing data (with the user having a FileChooser). Alternatively, you could sign your applet and request an AllPermission from the user - then you can access the file system.

Sorry, nothing of these answers your original question (I don't use IDEA), but maybe these help you to find another way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm going to try adding this in the jar file and attempt the getResourceAsStream() method as well as attempting to get permission from the user.  As you might have noticed it seems weird to use the working directory for an applet configuration.  This was attempted because we have a pre-existing desktop application that uses this method, and I wanted to attempt to convert it into a web applet with minimal work.

Comment: Also if no one can reply with the IDEA answer in 2 or 3 weeks, I'll just mark your answer as correct as it does give a lot of useful help.  Thanks.

Comment: It is also a bad idea for desktop applications to access application data (not user's data) by FileInputStream ... just since this does not allow putting the data in the applications jar file. And you are dependent on the current directory.

Comment: Yeah this was done because we wanted the users to have access to some configuration parameters and the easiest way we could think of at the time was to allow them to modify property files in the executables working directory.  If we had pushed this into the jar, we would have had to make an interface inside the application to allow for modification of these variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help in this matter Paulo.  While I couldn't find a direct answer to my question, I was able to use your first suggestion by including the config file in the jar building process and then loading it via: `InputStream configStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties");`  In this case, the config file is in the folder `config` which is in the root folder of the jar file.

Comment: Just a note: The context class loader might not always your own class loader (depending on the complexity of your application). If `MyClass` is a class of your own, you can simply use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/config.properties")` (note the extra `/` at the start), or `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties")`.

Comment: When using `getResourceAsStream()` it did not work the way it seemed.  My code that calls getResource in contained in a couple packages deep whereas the config folder is in the base folder.  It seems that I can only access it via the context class loader.